# MongoDB Aggregation: How to return documents with property which matches a value in an array?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have created a variable inside a mongoDB aggregation pipeline (`commentIds`). It is an array of mongo ObjectIds. In the 4th stage of the pipeline i want to return all CommentVotes documents who's `resourceId` property matches any of the ids in the `commentIds` array.

```
      const result = await this.aggregate([
        {
            //find articleVotes based on queryObj
            $match: {
                resourceId: {
                    $in: ids,
                },
            },
        },
        {
            //get commentIds
            $lookup: {
                from: Comment.collection.name,
                let: { articleId: '$resourceId' },
                pipeline: [
                    {
                        $match: {
                            $expr: {
                                $eq: ['$articleId', '$$articleId'],
                            },
                        },
                    },
                ],
                as: 'commentIds',
            },
        },
        {
            //convert array of objects to array of ids
            $addFields: {
                comemntIds: {
                    $map: {
                        input: '$commentIds',
                        as: 'obj',
                        in: '$$obj._id',
                    },
                },
            },
        },
        {
            //get commentVotes based on commentIds
            $lookup: {
                from: CommentVotesModel.collection.name,
                let: { commentIds: '$commentIds' },
                pipeline: [
                    {
                        $match: {
                            $expr: {
                                resourceId: {
                                    $in: '$$commentIds',
                                },
                            },
                        },
                    },
                ],
                as: 'commentVotes',
            },
        },
    ]);
```

The final stage is creating the following error: `$in needs an array`. However, having checked `commentIds` i can see it is an array, so I don't understand why i am getting this error. I have also checked it using `Array.isArray` which returns `true`.

You can see in the first stage i have used similar logic using an externally defined variable and it all works. It seems now i am using a variable internal to the pipeline, i am experiencing issues.

Can anyone help with this error?

**UPDATE**
I have added in the `let` expression based on @turivishals comments, and have used the `$expr` operator to allow me to access the `$$commentIds` variable inside the pipeline. However, this now means that i am using the `$in` aggregation operator (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/), rather than the query operator, which does not do what i want. Is there a away around this?

Comment: you have to pass `commentIds` in `let` of `$lookup` and use `$expr` to match $in condition, same as like your second lookup stage.

Comment: second you don't need third `$addFields` stage to get all `commentIds`, just use simple lookup and pass fields name it will manage to join and match all comment ids from array of object, `{ $lookup: { localField: "commentIds._id", foreignField: "resourceId", from: CommentVotesModel.collection.name, as: "commentVotes" } }`

Comment: thanks. I have made the first adjustment but this hasnt solved the error. I have updated the question to reflect the change. The 3rd stage is there to convert from an array of docs/objects to an array of just the ids.

Comment: please read the first comment again, use `$expr` to match `$in` condition, same as like your second lookup stage, because if you want to match internal fields in match stage you have to match inside `$expr`.

Comment: yes i also added that in before - sorry, forgot to mention that in my response. This creates a separate issue as i am now using the aggregation version of `$in`

Comment: still its wrong syntax again look at the `$expr` in second lookup stage,  does your condition lookes same? correct one is `{  $expr: { $in: ["$resourceId", "$$commentIds"] } }`